# Splitter behaviour with parallel processing

Tags: apache-camel

I have this route which exhibits a behaviour that I can't understand.

```
from("sftp://...)
    .autoStartup(isReadyToStart())
    .routeId(model.getName())
    .filter().method(startTrigger)
        .bean(RouteHelperIn.class,"start")
        .bean(initialize)
        .bean(RouteHelperIn.class, "startChunk")
        .convertBodyTo(InputStream.class)
        .split().tokenize(newLine)
                         .streaming()
                         .stopOnException()
                         .executorServiceRef(splitterExecutorService)
            .filter().method(RouteHelperIn.class,"isContentRow") //Skip header rows using the removeFirstLines route parameter
                .unmarshal(jdf)
                .bean(mapper)
                .bean(RouteHelperIn.class, "generateAndUpdateLog")
                .bean(writeToDb)
            .end()
        .end()
        .bean(RouteHelperIn.class, "endChunk")
        .bean(postProcessing).to("direct://" + sub.getCopy())
        .bean(RouteHelperIn.class, "writeLastImportLog")
        .bean(RouteHelperIn.class, "end")
    .end()
```

Let's suppose that the SFTP consumer find two files, and that `splitterExecutorService` is set to `null`.

In this case, the split is executed without parallelism and the two exchanges are executed sequentially. This is true because the second `RouteHelperIn#start` method is called after `RouteHelperIn#stop`, as expected.

When `splitterExecutorService` is set, then parallelism in the splitter is enabled. According to the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/split-eip.html#_ending_a_split_block):

> If enabled then processing each split messages occurs concurrently. Note **the caller thread will still wait until all messages has been fully processed, before it continues**. It’s only processing the sub messages from the splitter which happens concurrently.

What I see is that the second `RouteHelperIn#start` is started **before** than the first `RouteHelperIn#end`, and that is not what I was expecting, causing a serious bug in my scenario. Also, it seems that the thread ID is always the same, so the documentation is not respected. I was expecting the same behaviour than the previous case, with the only difference being that the steps described inside the splitter block were executed in parallel.

Could it be a bug in Apache Camel or am I making some wrong assumption here? I'm using version **3.11.3** now.

**UPDATE**
I've found that adding `synchronous=true` to the consumer URI solves the problem, IOW it behaves as expected. What I don't understand is why the route consumer is synchronous when the splitter is not parallelized and it's asynchronous when the splitter is parallelized, again according to what the documentation states.